# Why did they have to board the command ship to take out the second control tower?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker;

> The sith fleet commander deactivates the ground-based control tower, leading to the resistance fleet landing on the command ship to take out the aerial on that ship.

Yet, later in the same battle;

> Just shooting the underslung planet-killing ray gun seems to take out star destroyers with ease

Why didn't the resistance fleet just bomb the command ship with Y-wings, or shoot the aerial, or blow the ship up like they did with the others?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The command ship didn't have any planet crackers, if you remember when Finn got his 'feeling' there is a clear shot of the underside of the ship, no gun, so no easy gun exploding.

Simply flying above the ship with bombers (of which they had...I only remember a couple) is especially dangerous as there are hundreds of deck mounted guns blasting at them from 10, 000 destroyers, which was the entire point of flying at or below the destroyers to begin with.

The only choice at this point was a 'deck raid'. Which was successful in blowing up the tower, but Finn realized again at this point he needed to completely up the main bridge since they were just going to restart their systems and send the signal somewhere else.

Comment: Actually, that makes a lot of sense.